# Uplink DTMF tone generation

Tags: android, dtmf

Is there any way I can dynamically generate uplink DTMF tone (ie the receiver hears it)?

When I looked at the android source code I saw a function called `startDTMF()` which is exactly what I need, but I couldn't find any API that allows me to access that function...

I then thought of using ToneGenerator and tried to inject the sound to the mic stream, and again I couldn't find a way to achieve this...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 2013's update: yes, it's possible. Short sum-up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726229/how-to-create-auto-answering-machine-for-android/20025926#20025926

Comment: did you find any way to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [android.media.ToneGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) class in the SDK can help?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it's only good for generating downlink dtmf tone (ie what YOU hear). As I mentioned I tried to find a way to inject the audio to the mic stream but no luck... :(

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: For completeness, [here's the Android doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) where it specifically states: "This API is not for generating tones over the uplink audio path." Too bad, because it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

> tel:1234,123

this can help.
, generates a 4 sec delay so you may use this at places sometimes... 
but still we need to get some thing from sdk lets hope Android guys find something up!