# Android: Is it possible to have an app talk to the caller during a phone call?

Tags: android

I want to have an app answer calls and talk to the caller, like and answering machine but more advanced. Basically the app will pick up on every call, and talk to the caller until they hang up. Is this possible (even with hacks/workarounds)?

Comment: The answer used to be "No"  [How to create auto answering machine for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726229/).  It looks like this has changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924618/how-can-incoming-calls-be-answered-programmatically-in-android-5-0-lollipop

Comment: @FoggyDay Yeah I was looking at that second thread, but unless I'm mistaken, it says nothing about how send/receive all of the audio data